# Modifiying time in LocalTimeDate object

Tags: java, jsr310

Given a `LocalDateTime` object in Java. How do I set the time for this to 00:00:00 ?
One way is to create a new `LocalDateTime` object with the same date as this one and set it to 0.
Is there another way to do it?

Comment: No, there is no way to set the time in an existing `LocalDateTime` object. The object is immutable. As most objects of classes of java.time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A given `LocalDateTime` object can not be modified, since those are immutable. But you can get a new `LocalDateTime` object with the desired dates.

There are several ways to do this (all assuming `ldt` is the input and `atMidnight` is a variable of type `LocalDateTime`):

1. `atMidnight = ldt.with(LocalTime.MIDNIGHT)` (preferred method)
2. `atMidnight = ldt.truncatedTo(ChronoUnit.DAYS)`
3. `atMidnight = ldt.toLocalDate().atStartOfDay()`

Lastly, if you really meant "with no time", then you can simply convert the `LocalDateTime` to a `LocalDate` using `toLocalDate`.

Comment: A very full answer. Thanks.

Comment: As the author of JSR-310, I can say that `ldt.with(LocalTime.MIDNIGHT)` is the way that users are expected to do this.

Comment: @JodaStephen could you briefly explain the thought process behind .with function. As you mentioned, that's the way users are expected to do it rather than various other approached

Comment: `with()` replaces one part of the target object with another thing. Here it replaces the time in a `LocalDateTime`, but it could replace the date, or just the year. It is a generally useful, method, and is conceptually high level unlike truncating

Answer (score 1):

If you look at `LocalDateTime` you'll see:

```
    /**
     * The date part.
     */
    private final LocalDate date;
    /**
     * The time part.
     */
    private final LocalTime time;
```

So `LocalDateTime` is immutable. This is good because it means that you can pass an instance to other code without worrying that it might get modified, and simplifies access from multiple threads.

I does mean that you will need to create a new instance to modify the time.

Answer (score 1):

`LocalDateTime` is immutable, meaning you cannot change a `LocalDateTime` object (only create new objects). If you use modifying operations, another `LocalDateTime` object is created.

You could obviously create another object manually but you can also get a `LocalDate`-object using `.toLocalDate` and get a `LocalDateTime`-object again using `.atStartOfDay`:

```
yourLocalDateTime.toLocalDate().atStartOfDay()
```